# How to shift basemap in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, basemap

I have some very precise vector data (within 10cm) that I collected myself. It falls about 33m away from the same point on the basemap.

All basemaps (Google, Bing, OSM, ESRI, EOX, etc.) align well among themselves, but that's probably because they were georeferenced after whichever was the first one, which was wrong.

It is quite annoying to use such a bad basemap, and I would like to be able to temporarily (or per project) shift it so that it aligns with accurately surveyed data.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom CRS, based on the CRS of the basemap, e.g. EPSG:3857 for Google Maps, with False Easting and False Northing set to (minus) the difference between a surveyed control point and the same point, digitized on the base map, as measured on the CRS of the basemap (3857).

As measured on basemap CRS, e.g. 3857 :

```
False_Easting  = Digitized_Easting  - Surveyed_Easting
False_Northing = Digitized_Northing - Surveyed_Northing
```

1. Set the project CRS to basemap CRS (3857)
2. Digitize on the basemap a point that corresponds to a surveyed point
3. Calculate False Easting/Northing
4. Settings -> Custom Projections... -> + -> Give it a name
5. Copy the ESRI WKT* of the basemap CRS (3857)
6. Modify the name of the CRS in the WKT as well so that it's unique. Just give it a namespace
7. Modify the False Easting/Northing appropriately, as calculated in step 3.
8. Set the CRS of the basemap (right click on basemap layer -> Layer CRS -> Set Layer CRS) to the newly created CRS
9. Enjoy a properly aligned local basemap!

*no clue why ESRI WKT is what QGIS understands, but if you go for OGC WKT or OGC WKT2, it will validate correctly with the validate button, but then it says it's invalid when clicking ok to save the new CRS.